# Spring Integration - parallel file processing by group

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to use experiment with Spring Integration with a simple task. I have a folder where I get incoming files. The files are named after a group ID. 
I want all the files in the same groupId to be processed in sequence but files with different groupIds can be processed in parallel.

I started putting together a configuration like this:

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="filesInChannel"
    output-channel="outputChannelAdapter">
    <bean class="com.ingestion.FileProcessor" />
</int:service-activator>

<int:channel id="filesInChannel" />

<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="inputChannelAdapter"
    channel="filesInChannel" directory="${in.file.path}" prevent-duplicates="true"
    filename-pattern="${file.pattern}">

    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-rate="1" task-executor="executor"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="outputChannelAdapter" directory="${ok.file.path}" delete-source-files="true"/>

<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="10"/>
```

This is processing all the incoming files with 10 threads. What are the steps I need to split the files by groupId and have them processed one thread per groupId?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a finite number of group ids, you could use a different adapter for each group (with a single thread; all feeding into the same channel); each with a different pattern.

Or you could create a custom `FileListFilter` and use some kind of thread affinity to assign files from each group to a specific thread, with the filter only returning this thread's file(s).

Comment: Thanks. Well to give you more detail, what I was hoping to do is dynamically adjust the number of active threads that are processing the file and do a mod on the group ID with the number of available threads. Do we need to create a different adapter for each group for this? What if say I have a thousand different groups - would spring integration have a way to asssign a adapter for each groupId%numberOfGroups?